# how divide series of columns to one column

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a DataSET with more than 5e5 individuals as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
sample <- tibble( 
  iD=c(1,2),
  age=c(38,40), born_1=c(14,1),born_2=c(9,NA), born_3=c(4,NA),  born_4=c(0,NA), asfr15=c( 0.0000), asfr16=c( 
    7.40444, 7.40444),  
  asfr17=c( 42.87749, 7.40444),  asfr18=c(73.05321, 7.40444),asfr19=c(98.28869, 7.40444),asfr20=c( 144.9568, 7.40444),asfr21= c
    (164.976,180.280),asfr22=c(180.280,180.280),asfr23=c(191.304,180.280),asfr24=c(200.199,180.280),asfr25=c(200.2018,180.280),
  asfr26=c(200.2007,180.280),asfr27=c( 200.3920,180.280),asfr28=c(197.6840,180.280),asfr29=c( 193.7632,180.280),
  asfr30=c(187.6072,180.280),asfr31=c(179.5616,180.280),asfr32=c( 170.5096,180.280),asfr33=c( 160.8376,180.280),asfr34=c( 
    150.4840,180.280),asfr35=c( 139.3304,180.280),asfr36=c( 127.7960,180.280),asfr37=c( 115.0280,180.280),asfr38=c( 100.7200,180.280),
  asfr39=c(85.6256,180.280),asfr40=c( 182.4384,180.280),asfr41=c( 178.412,180.280),asfr42=c( 171.928,180.280), asfr43=c( 
    163.316,180.280),asfr44=c( 152.9056,180.280),asfr45=c( 141.0264,180.280),asfr46=c( 128.008,180.280),asfr47=c( 114.180,180.280),asfr48=c( 
      99.872,180.280), asfr49=c( 85.4136,180.280))
```

I need to divide asfr15 through asfr49 to 1000 and then calculate their sum:

```
    sample3<- mutate(sample2, TFR=(rowSums(sample2[,7:41]))/1000)
```

and after that, I need to divide the columns [,7:41] to The TFR calculated in the previous line:

```
    sample4<-((sample3[,2:36])/1000) / sample3[,49]
```

The codes, I have written, do the work, but other columns I have still needed, are omitted. I must keep columns [,1:6] and the colums[,7:41] with the original name. (no change in Name of columns)

Comment: There is no need to divide by 1000. It cancels out

Comment: Do you want *the columns [, 7:41]* or *[, 2:36]* to be divided by `TFR`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
asfr1549 <- paste0("asfr", 15:49)
TFR <- rowSums(sample[, asfr1549]) / 1e3
# modify data in place, do not store TFR as column of sample  
sample[, asfr1549] <- sample[, asfr1549] / TFR
sample[, asfr1549]
# optional: remove objects from environment
# rm(asfr1549, TFR)
```

This is simple base R code. If you like to add `TFR` as column, just replace all `TFR` with `sample$TFR`. I am unsure about the repeated division by `1000`(`1e3`). If you really want to do that, it is sufficient to devide by `1e6` once.

Comment: (A) I need to change the values in columns asfr15 til asfr49

Answer (score 2):

I *think* the requirement is to:

- replace the values in columns asfr15-asfr49 with the proportion of their row total
- do the same for a bunch of further groups of columns, foo15-foo49, bar15-bar49 etc.
- keep the dimension, column names and initial 6 attribute columns of the dataframe unchanged

If so this can be done as follows. (The question is tagged with dplyr and data.table, and I will use the latter.) The trick is to reshape to long, compute by group, and reshape back to wide. Then it doesn't matter what the groups and their suffixes are (as long as the suffixes are two characters).

```
library(data.table)

setDT(sample)
    
# convert to long
df <- melt(sample,
           id.vars=c("iD", "age", "born_1", "born_2", "born_3", "born_4"),
           variable.factor=T,
           variable.name="col_name_fct")    

# split the original column names into group and suffix
df[, col_name := as.character(col_name_fct)][, col_name_len := nchar(col_name)]
df[, ':=' (col_group  = substr(col_name, 1, col_name_len-2),
           col_suffix = substr(col_name, col_name_len-1, col_name_len))]

# compute the proportions by group
df[, value := value/sum(value, na.rm=T), by=.(col_group, iD)]

# convert back to wide with the original column names and order
df <- dcast(df, iD+age+born_1+born_2+born_3+born_4 ~ col_name_fct)
```

Note that reading the column names as a factor at the melt stage preserves their order (e.g. "foo" group before "bar" group) when the data are pivoted back to wide format.

Comment: Cannot run your apporach. `let()` from package `{wrapr}`?

Comment: @Friede `let()` is a synonym for `':='()` in data.table v1.14.9 (dev). I'll change it to `':='()`, and thanks for raising

Comment: @Friede did a bit of renaming while I was at it, to make it clearer what is going on

Comment: Thanks for letting us know about `let()`.  I understand your approach. In my opinion, it is a bit heavy-handed for the simple task at hand still.

Comment: I'm all for a simple solution but we don't know what the task at hand is. The OP seems to say they already have code that works for asfr15-asfr49. If they need to process multiple groups of columns in a similar way then they will need a solution like this. But if it's just one set of columns, then yes absolutely, all this pivoting about is not required!